# Error building geometry stack in OSX

Tags: python, eigen, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to build the geometry stack on osx Lion bu I got the following error during the building of Eigen:

```
mkdir -p build
if [ ! -f eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2.md5sum" && false; fi
`rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/eigen/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2 build/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2 `awk {'print $1'} eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2.md5sum`
[rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/eigen/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2 to build/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luca/Software/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 56, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/luca/Software/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 28, in main
    urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 204, in open
    return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 216, in open_unknown
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'unknown url type', type)
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: 'https'
make: *** [build/eigen/unpacked] Error 1
```

Do you know how I can fix it? I read somewhere that I should switch to urllib2 but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10887/error-building-geometry-stack-in-osx/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2011-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a better solution:

```
cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/
sudo cp /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.so .
```

I don't know way bu it seems that the `_ssl.do` module is not installed through macport.

---

Originally posted by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) with karma: 128 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0